# Joomla 3.6 Authentication and Login

Tags: cookies, authentication, joomla, token

I' m having a difficulty in getting a clear view on Joomla (I'm using version 3.6.x) authentication and login.
I've seen many approaches and snippets on how to "Login" in a Joomla site from an external source (which is what i m interesting in).
But what i see after testing and testing (and more testing), is that at the end of the day, you re simply not logged in.
You may have the ability to verify that the user who's attempting to login is a valid registered user and also to be able to retrieve his name, email, phone and blah blah blah but in Joomla backend, this user is still not logged in.
I created a brand new user in Administrator Panel (it shows the user NEVER visited the site), I wrote the login script in external PHP, I "authenticated" the new user a dozen times and when i go back to the Backend, the user still NEVER been there. Not even once.
Which, i guess, it also means that i can't retrieve a list of "active" users, since Joomla can't see them as logged in users.

So what i want to achieve is users to be able to login from outside the Joomla site and to have the ability to know IF they're logged in or not. So I can get a list of them and assign tasks to them.
I guess it has something to do with tokens and cookies. But no matter how much i searched to that direction, i can't find any examples to enlighten me.
Any help (and specially "scripting" help) is much appreciated.
Thank you.

```
<?php
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<')) {
            die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
        }

        define('_JEXEC', 1);

        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php')) {
            include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
        }

        if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
            define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
            require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
        }

        require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

        $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
        $app->initialise();

        require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');


        $credentials['username'] = $_GET["usrname"];
        $credentials['password'] = $_GET["passwd"];

        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('id, password')
            ->from('#__users')
            ->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObject();

        if ($result) {
            $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);

            if ($match === true) {
                $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);
                $session =& JFactory::getSession();

                echo "<p>Your name is {$user->name}, your email is {$user->email}, and your username is {$user->username}</p>";

                $session->set('userid', $user->id);

                if ($user->guest) {
                    echo 'SORRY, NO LOGIN YET...';
                } else {
                    echo 'user is LOGGED IN !';
                }

            } else {
                die('Invalid password');
            }
        } else {
            die('Cound not find user in the database');
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Joomla log in is handled in authentication plugins, by writing and enabling your own you can bypass the token verification and allow logging in by a simple get request.

Keep in mind that Joomla! keeps *administrator* and *frontend* sessions separate (you can be logged into the administrator, and browse the site as a guest). Additionally, a user needs a Manager, Administrator or Super User group membership to login to the backend.

**Administrator**

The common use case for admin login is to run a background script.
In order to bypass the Joomla Authentication in the backend, check out the /cli folder as it contains some examples.

**Frontend**

The use case for frontend login is much wider: server-to-server communication, app authentication, single sign on etc.

The best practice to perform frontend authentication is to build your own authentication plugin.  The authentication will be implemented by the onUserAuthenticate() function. Check out the `/plugins/authentication/joomla/`  plugin for an example.

If you need extra data for the authentication plugin to perform its magic (e.g. the remote token/api key to authenticate using a remote service) you might want to check out the user plugin group, for example the `/plugins/user/profile` plugin.

**Verify last login date/time**

The frontend approach should automatically work, showing users as logged in in the administrator control panel.

However, if you use the CLI approach to login to the administrator, this may not work depending on how you perform login.

Comment: Now to make something more clear.
I'm not interested in bypassing the Administrator login. I want to control the whole thing as Administrator.
But the users (not all but just a few who work here, need to sign in from a different platform).
This is the part i'm stuck.
Even the authentication works perfectly, it still works JUST as an authentication and not as a permission to login.
Something like "yes you're a part of us but you stay out of here".
I'll have a look again at the plugins and thank you a lot for your time to reply me.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to check if a user is logged in only authentication is not enough but you need a forced login. Only then you will be able to view them at the backend. 
This is the code you can use to check if a user is logged in or not

```
<?php
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<')) {
    die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
}
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');

define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('JPATH_BASE', "C:\Vertrigo\www\joomla" );//Define the Base path as per your installation directory

if (!defined('_JDEFINES'))
{
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');
//Check if a user exists else create one with forced login   
$user = JFactory::getUser();
jimport('joomla.plugin.helper');

$credentials = array();
$credentials['username'] = JRequest::getVar('username', '');
$credentials['password'] = JRequest::getVar('passwd', '');

if (!$user->get('gid')){
    $forcevars = array();
    $forcevars['silent'] = true;
    $forcevars['forecelogon'] = true;
    $response = $app->login($credentials, $forcevars);
    if($response){
        echo "Login Successful";
    }else{
        echo "Login Unsuccessful. Check Username and Password. Give just Plain password.";
    }
}
?>
```

I have modified the code as you neeeded to call username and password in url. better to use getVar in joomla rather than GET method. You url will be in the format `http://www.yoursite.com/thisscript.php?username=yourusername&passwd=yourpassword`

Comment: i don't know what i do wrong but i just changed the path in JPATH_BASE to my localhost joomla installation 
and the 'username', 'password' in the $credentials to actual values.
All I get is
"The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"
Any ideas ?

Comment: Surprising why its showing error but as you said you were able to do successful authentication why don.t you keep your top codes same and just change the login codes in your authentication files. Also check in base path there should not be any trailing slash '/'.

Comment: The problem is not to "authenticate". The authentication script is correct and working fine. The problem is that when i authenticate the user, the backend doesnt show him as logged in. I want to be able to retrieve a list of the logged in users without having to do it manually. The PHP file who does the authentication can contain some code to store each authenticated user in a list. But i m afraid i will have too much trouble adding many different pieces of code and files.

Comment: I am not asking you to authenticate but to use part of your script that you used to authenticate users. And use only the login part which I have given. Or just add this part starting from `$user = JFactory::getUser();` upto `echo "Login Unsuccessful. Check Username and Password. Give just Plain password.";
    }` to your authentication script. Can you show me your authentication script?

Comment: Hello again Amit.
I stripped down the code from GNUs and comments but it still seems to be too long for here.
Do you mind telling me how to post it ? 
By using several messages ? 
I'll give it a try...

Comment: `
 <?php
  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<')){
   die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');
  }
  define('_JEXEC', 1);
  if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php')) {
   include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';
  }
  if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
   define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
   require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
  }
  require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
  $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
  $app->initialise(); 
  require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');
`

Comment: You could have used pastebin.com

Comment: I just checked it but I was not asking for the code which i gave, I was asking for the code that you used previously to authenticate users.

Comment: `<?php`
 `if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.1', '<')){`
  `die('Your host needs to use PHP 5.3.1 or higher to run this version of Joomla!');`
 `}`
 `define('_JEXEC', 1);`
 `if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/defines.php')) {`
  `include_once __DIR__ . '/defines.php';`
 `}`
 `if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {`
  `define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);`
  `require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';`
 `}`
 `require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';`
 `$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');`
 `$app->initialise();`
 `require_once (JPATH_BASE .'/libraries/joomla/factory.php');`

Comment: The code in general or in all is based on the Joomla! External Authentication Script. This was the code which i used or better 1/3rd of it since i cant find a way to post it all. I'm terribly sorry for my messed up code messages but i m trying to find a way to improve them.

Comment: In this code give the base path manually where you have installed joomla `define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);` will take some other directory.

Comment: I updated the code in the main question. i call this script by "/signin.php?usrname=niko&passwd=0000" and i get this result...:  "Your name is Νίκος, your email is test@hotmail.com, and your username is niko

user is LOGGED IN !"

Comment: So is it working now. By the way I have updated the code for you where you need to login through url..

Comment: I m afraid not. I execute your script with local joomla folder and I also changed the "username" to "usrname" cause its misstyped in your script. All I get is a blank screen and the last visit of the user in the backend is still NEVER.

Comment: It is not mistyped if you give usrname it will not recognise as in my code i have used username. You could have used the url like this "/signin.php?username=niko&passwd=0000" without changing code. You just need to change basepath.

Comment: To get error message I have modified the code. So you can know where the error is exactly.

Comment: "username" or "usrname" i still get a blank page. no error messages or any messages at all. But in any case I'm really so thankful for the time you re spending for me.

Comment: Can you post the entire code in pastebin.com without any changes. dont change even your base path. Paste the link here.